# Set checkboxes on edit method in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Suppose I have a form in new.html.erb with some checkboxes and select tags and other text_fields. And suppose I create a record (check one or more checkboxes and select something) and save it to DB successfully. 
When I go to edit.html.erb which should edit this record I have the following situation:

1) All text_fields are filled with the values of that record I want to edit (OK)

2) But checkboxes are all unchecked (NOT OK)

3) Nothing is selected in select tag (NOT OK)

So 2nd and 3rd points are problematic. 
How to populate checkboxes and select tag when editing a record?

MY EXAMPLE:
I  have a collection_select:

```html
<%= f.collection_select :type, RequestType.order(:typeName), :id, :typeName, {include_blank:true }, {:class => "types"} %>
```

And a checkboxes that are actually generated depending on select tag value (this works).

```html
<% @stypes.each do |stype| %>
            <span class="sub_type_cbox">
          <%= check_box_tag 'stype_ids[]', stype.id %>
                <%= stype.subTypeName %>
         </span>
            <br>
 <% end %>
```

### When checking many checkboxes their values are stored as an array in DB. For example:

- '1'
- '2'
  Means that checkbox 1 and 2 are selected (those are actually id's).

Comment: Can you show your form code please.

Comment: try this for check box, <%= check_box_tag :stype_ids, stype.id, :name => 'stype[stype_ids][]' %>

Comment: @djrock, oh no it is not working, actually it checks checkbox regardless of the value in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the checkboxes, `check_box_tag` allows a third parameter which is whether it's checked.  So we can simply check to see if the object already has that stype.  It'd be easier to use the object you've bound the form to but as you've not posted the full form I can't see what that is.  So you can change `f.object` to `@post` or whatever it's bound to.

```
<% @stypes.each do |stype| %>
  <span class="sub_type_cbox">
    <%= check_box_tag 'stype_ids[]', stype.id, f.object.stype_ids.include?(stype.id) %>
    <%= stype.subTypeName %>
  </span>
  <br>
 <% end %>
```

For the select you simply pass into the method what was selected.  Again you can replace `f.object` with whatever you bound the form to.

```
<%= f.collection_select :type, RequestType.order(:typeName), :id, :typeName, { selected: f.object.type, include_blank:true }, {:class => "types"} %>
```

Comment: collection_select works fine. But checkboxes are still unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for solution. but I had to pass (stype.id) like that --> ("#{stype.id}"). I figured it out after playing with it in console and noticed that passing ("1") is different that just (1). I guess it distinguishes between string and int.