# Populating checkboxes based on db in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, populate

I'm working on this reconciliation system where users can choose which fields they would like to use when importing records. I finally got the select to pre-populate with the correct info but can't for the life of me get the checkboxes to do the same. Here's my form:

```
    #views/match_rule/edit.html.erb

    <%= form_for(@match_rules) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Rule Set Name" %>
    <%= f.label :algorithm, "Choose an algorithm" %>
    <%= f.select :algorithm, build_algorithm_select_options %>
    <%= f.label :match_fields, "Available fields" %>
    <% @field_options.each do |field| %>
      <%= f.check_box :match_fields %>
      <%= f.label :match_fields, "#{field.last}" %><br/>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", match_rule_index_path, class: "button" %>
  <% end %>
```

Currently the corresponding controller is simply building a hash of fields so not to clutter up the view with repetitive code

```
  #controllers/match_rule_controller.rb

  def edit
    @field_options = {
      name: "Name",
      email: "Email",
      phone: "Phone Number",
      gender: "Gender",
      marital_status: "Marital Status",
      dob: "Date of Birth",
      campus: "Campus",
      address: "Street Address",
      city: "City",
      state: "State",
      zip: "Zip"
    }
  end
```

My model is serializing the fields

```
#models/match_rule.rb

class MatchRule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inboxes
  enum algorithm: [ :adjustable, :classic_minimal, :classic_standard ]
  serialize :match_fields
end
```

and my database fields are storing all the options that should populate the checkboxes in the match_fields column
[image: screenshot of the db structure]

If it helps to see how I seeded the db with an array here's that:

```
#db/seeds.rb

classic_minimal = MatchRule.create(algorithm: 'classic_minimal', match_fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'gender', 'zip'], name: 'Classic Minimal')
classic_standard = MatchRule.create(algorithm: 'classic_standard', match_fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'gender', 'marital_status', 'dob', 'campus', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip'], name: 'Classic Standard')
adjustable = MatchRule.create(algorithm: 'adjustable', match_fields: ['name', 'phone', 'campus', 'marital_status', 'zip'], name: 'Adjustable')
```

I've checked out similar questions on here, the one closest to helping me have a breakthrough was the answer to this question: [Set checkboxes on edit method in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746271/set-checkboxes-on-edit-method-in-rails-4) where he says to use .include? to determine the checked status, but I'm not sure what I would put in the params because I need to parse through the hash inside match_fields for each and every field and that would get pretty gnarly.

Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**
Update! Tried using fields_for but still not posting or populating.

```
<%= f.label :match_fields, "Available fields" %>
<%= fields_for :match_fields do |field| %>
<%= field.check_box :name %>
<%= field.label :name, "Name" %><br/>
<%= field.check_box :email %>
<%= field.label :email, "Email" %><br/>
<%= field.check_box :phone %>
<%= field.label :phone, "Phone" %><br/>
<% end %>
```

now when I check params on update in the console, it's saying:

```
  "match_fields" => {
 "name" => "1",
"email" => "1",
"phone" => "0"
},
```

but not actually posting or populating.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
      <%= form_for(@match_rules) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Rule Set Name" %>
        <%= f.label :algorithm, "Choose an algorithm" %>
        <%= f.select :algorithm, build_algorithm_select_options %>
        <%= f.label :match_fields, "Available fields" %>
<%= f.check_box :name, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("name") } %>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :email, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("email") }  %>
        <%= f.label :email, "Email" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :phone, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("phone") } %>
        <%= f.label :phone, "Phone" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :gender, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("gender") } %>
        <%= f.label :gender, "Gender" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :marital_status, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("marital_status") } %>
        <%= f.label :marital_status, "Marital Status" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :dob, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("dob") } %>
        <%= f.label :dob, "Date of Birth" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :campus, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("campus") } %>
        <%= f.label :campus, "Campus" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :address, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("address") } %>
        <%= f.label :address, "Street Address" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :city, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("city") } %>
        <%= f.label :city, "City" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :state, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("state") } %>
        <%= f.label :state, "State" %><br/>
        <%= f.check_box :zip, { checked: @match_rules.match_fields.include?("zip") } %>
        <%= f.label :zip, "Zip Code" %><br/>
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", match_rule_index_path, class: "button" %>
```

You have to pass the .include? method inside the options hash. Now I just need to find a cleaner way to put this in the view.